# Can I install monocular helm standalone?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Seems that I always need to install Monocular for Helm in a Kubernetes Cluster. However, I wonder if I can install it standalone and use it as a front end to browse Helm repositories. If so, where can I find the installation instructions to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be deployed in a pod in your infrastructure. Take a look at [official doc](https://github.com/helm/monocular#install)